# Find the area of square $ABCD$

Tags: calculus, coordinate-systems, curves

> A square $ABCD$ has all its vertices on the curve $x^2y^2=1$. The mid points of its side also lie on the same curve. Find the area of square $ABCD$.

I drew the graph of $x^2y^2=1$. It is a discontinuous curve having two points of discontinuity.

Then I assumed coordinates of the vertices and put them in the equation of curve. But I got nothing.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint…If one of the vertices is $(t,\frac1t)$, can you identify the coordinates of another vertex (using symmetry)? Find the midpoint and use the equation of the curve to find the value of $t$

Comment: This must be the hardest square area in the world!

Comment: @NoChance I'm obviously taking it as a sarcasm

Comment: The problem is not trivial. At least for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

$x^2y^2=1 \iff xy=1,-1$. So I have two equilateral hyperbolas in the $4$ quadrants. Let be $A=(t_1,\frac1{t_1})$ with $t_1>0$ that lie in the vertex of the square in the first quadrant. $D=(-t_2,-\frac1{t_2})$ with $t_2>0$ that lie in the vertex of the square in the second quadrant. Let be $C=(-t_1,-\frac1{t_1})$ that lie in the vertex of the square in the third quadrant. At least let be $B=(t_2,-\frac1{t_2})$ that lie in the vertex of the square in the fourth quadrant. Then

$$\frac{t_1+t_2}{2}\cdot \frac{\frac1{t_1}-\frac1{t_2}}{2}=1 \implies t_1^2-t_2^2=4t_1t_2$$$$\frac{1}{t^2_1}\cdot \left(-\frac{1}{t^2_2}\right)=-1\implies t_1^2-t_2^2=4$$

$$t^2_1+t_2^2=\sqrt{4^2+4}=2\sqrt5$$

$$t_1^2=2+\sqrt 5 \quad \mapsto \quad \frac{1}{t^2_1}=\sqrt 5-2$$

Therefore

$$|AB|^2=(t_1-t_2)^2+\left(\frac{1}{t_1}+\frac{1}{t_2}\right)^2=2\left(t_1^2+\frac{1}{t^2_1}\right)=2\left(2+\sqrt{5}+\frac{1}{2+\sqrt{5}}\right)$$
$$2\cdot \left(2\sqrt{5}\right)=4\sqrt 5$$

Comment: @NoChance Why the side length of the square must be 1?

Comment: There are some arguments missing, I think. For example, why are vertices on different branches of hyperbolae? Why does the center of the square coincide with the origin? For the first question, easiest way out is using midpoints, if adjacent vertices were on the same branch, midpoint couldn't be on the branch due to convexity. For the second question, let's say that the center is in the (open) first quadrant. Rotating hyperbola xy = 1 by 180 degrees around the center of the square will never give us intersection with the original hyperbola in the third quadrant, relatively easy calculation.

Comment: 1) For example, why are vertices on different branches of hyperbolae? A: see the graph that I have put and read the question. 2) Why does the center of the square coincide with the origin? A: If you draw the diagonals they intersect at the origin.

Comment: In fact, the point (1,1) is just on of the possible solutions since it would satisfy $x^2y^2=1$. Please see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345689/how-many-squares-with-vertices-on-x2y2-1-are-possible

Comment: @Sebastiano, you answered none of my questions actually, more precisely your arguments are circular, but it doesn't matter to me since I know how to answer them and actually wrote argumentation myself in my previous comment if you read carefully. That comment was meant for other readers.

Comment: @NoChance, you missed the sentence: "The mid points of its side also lie on the same curve." The square you linked us clearly doesn't have that property, since the midpoints lie on the axes.

Comment: @Ennar The drawing is only a draft. Now there is boojum's drawing which is better than mine.

Comment: @Sebastiano, you are not understanding what I'm saying. Your drawing is great, but it's not a proof that there isn't some other square that satisfies conditions given in the exercise but is essentially different from the square you've drawn (essentially meaning the center is not in the origin or vertices are not all on different branches). In short, you found one solution, but you didn't prove that it's the only solution.

Comment: @Ennar, thanks for brining my attention to this.

Answer (score 3):

The curve for $ \ x^2·y^2 \ = \ 1 \ \rightarrow \ xy \ = \ \pm 1 \ $ has "four-fold" symmetry about the origin: if $ \ (x \ , \ y) \ $ is a point on the curve, so are $ \ (x \ , \ -y) \ , \ (-x \ , \ y) \ , \ $ and $ \ (-x \ , \ -y) \ \ . \ $  The requirement that the square must have both its vertices *and* the midpoints of its sides lie on the curve means that *two* points  of the square must be located on each "branch".  This makes it impossible for the sides of the square to be parallel to the coordinate  axes, since either the set of vertices or the set of midpoints would not be accommodated; this forces us to look for a solution in which the square is canted at some angle to the axes.  (The aforementioned symmetry will also locate  the center of the square at the origin, to respond to **Ennar**'s comment.)

We  then anticipate  a solution with one vertex on each branch of this "double rectangular hyperbola" in such a way that the side connecting "consecutive" vertices intersects the curve as well.  We then have one vertex and one midpoint on each branch.  The change in sign for the product of coordinates in the first and third *versus* the second and fourth quadrants "breaks" the four-fold symmetry for the square, but we still have a symmetry about the origin , placing the vertices  at $ \ \left(X \ , \ \frac{1}{X} \right) \ \ , \ \ \left(-X \ , \ -\frac{1}{X} \right) \ $ on $ \ xy \ = \ +1 \ $ and  $ \ \left(\frac{1}{X} \ , \ -X \right) \ \ , \ \ \left(-\frac{1}{X} \ , \ X \right) \ $ on $ \ xy \ = \ -1 \ \ ; \ $  in this designation, we have chosen $ \ X \ > \ \frac{1}{X} \ > \ 0 \ \ . \ $

The midpoints of the sides connecting consecutive vertices also "obey" this "partial-broken" symmetry.  In an earlier attempt, I found that making use of the geometry of a square only yielded relations that told nothing about its *size*. It turns out that the requirement that the midpoints of the sides lie on the branches on the curve "sets the scale" for the square.  So saying, we will call these midpoints $ \ \left(a \ , \ \frac{1}{a} \right) \ \ , \ \  \left(\frac{1}{a} \ , \ -a \right) \ \ ,$ $ \left(-a \ , \ -\frac{1}{a} \right) \ \ , \ \ $ and  $ \ \left(\frac{1}{a} \ , \ -a \right) \  . \ $  We will focus on the midpoint in the first quadrant and the vertices in the first and second, although a similar discussion would follow, with appropriate sign changes, for any of the other midpoints.  [**Sebastiano** presents a fine argument based on the requirement that the product of the coordinates of these midpoints must equal either $ \ +1 \ $ or $ \ -1 \ \ . \ $ An alternative approach is offered here.]

As the center of symmetry is the origin, we extend a segment to the midpoint at $ \ \left(a \ , \ \frac{1}{a} \right) \ \ ; \ $ this segment then has slope $ \ m' \ = \ \frac{1}{a^2} \ \ . \ $  The side of the square containing this point is perpendicular to the segment:  its slope is then $ \ m \ = \ -a^2 \ \ $ and this side lies on the line
$$ y \ - \ \frac{1}{a} \ \ = \ \ -a^2·(x \ - \ a) \ \ \rightarrow \ \ y \ \ = \ \ -a^2·x \ + \ a^3 \ + \ \frac{1}{a} \ \ . $$  We wish to find where this line intersects the branches of the "double hyperbola" in order to locate the vertices of this side of the square, so we need to solve the equations $ \ -a^2·x   +   a^3   +   \frac{1}{a} \ = \ \pm \frac{1}{x} \ \ . \ $  The vertex in the first quadrant is on the same branch as our midpoint, for which we find
$$ -a^2·x \ + \ a^3 \ + \ \frac{1}{a} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{x} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ a^3·x^2 \ - \ (a^4 \ + \ 1)·x \ + \ a $$ $$ = \ \ (a \ -  \ x)·(1 \ - \ a^3·x ) \ \ = \ \ 0 \ \ .  $$
This locates the first quadrant vertex at $ \ \left(\frac{1}{a^3} \ , \ a^3 \right) \ \ . \ $  The equation to find the vertex on the second-quadrant branch of $ \ y \ = \ -\frac{1}{x} \ $ is *far* less pleasant to solve, but here the anti-symmetry across coordinate axes comes to our rescue(!), giving us the coordinates as $ \ \left(-a^3  \ , \ \frac{1}{a^3}  \right) \ \ . \ $

The midpoint must be *equidistant* from these two vertices, so we can write
$$ \left(a \ - \ \frac{1}{a^3} \right)^2 \ + \ \left(\frac{1}{a} \ - \  a^3  \right)^2 \ \ = \  \  ( \ a \ - \ [-a^3] \ )^2 \ + \ \left(\frac{1}{a} \ - \ \frac{1}{a^3} \right)^2 $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  a^2  \ - \ \frac{2}{a^2} \ + \ \frac{1}{a^6} \ + \ \frac{1}{a^2} \ - \ 2·a^2 \ + \ a^6  $$ $$ =  \ \ a^2 \ + \  2·a^4 \ + \ a^6 \ + \ \frac{1}{a^2} \ - \ \frac{2}{a^4} \ + \ \frac{1}{a^6} \quad \mathbf{[ \ 1 \ ]} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \  a^4  \ - \ \frac{1}{a^4} \ + \ a^2 \ + \ \frac{1}{a^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{1}{a^4}·\left(   a^4 \ + \ 1  \right)· \left(  a^4 \ + \ a^2 \ - \ 1   \right) \ \ =  \ \ 0 \ \ . $$

Since $ \ a \ $ is a non-zero real number, only the quadratic factor above yields a solution, given by
$$ a^2 \ \ = \ \ -\frac12 \ + \ \frac{\sqrt{1^2 \ - \ 4·1·(-1)}}{2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{\sqrt5 \ - \ 1}{2} \ \ , $$
upon "discarding" the non-real result $ \ a^2 \ = \ -\frac{ \sqrt5 \ + \ 1}{2} \ \ . $  [One may recognize the acceptable value as $ \ a^2 \ = \ \frac{1}{\phi} \ \ , \ \ \phi \ $ being the "Golden Ratio".]

Either side of equation $ \ \mathbf{1} \ $ gives the distance-squared from the midpoint of the side of the square to one or the other of the vertices, so the area of the square is obtained from, say,

$$ \mathcal{A} \ \ = \ \ 4 · \left( \ a^6 \ + \ \frac{1}{a^6} \ - \ a^2  \ - \ \frac{1}{a^2}   \ \right) $$
$$ = \ \ 4 · \left[ \ \left(\frac{\sqrt5 \ - \ 1}{2} \right)^3 \ + \ \left(\frac{\sqrt5 \ + \ 1}{2} \right)^3 \ - \ \left(\frac{\sqrt5 \ - \ 1}{2} \right)  \ - \ \left(\frac{\sqrt5 \ + \ 1}{2} \right)   \ \right] \ \ $$
[using $ \ \frac{1}{a^2} \ = \ \frac{\sqrt5 \ + \ 1}{2} \ ] $

$$ = \ \ \frac48 · [ \  (\sqrt5 \ - \ 1)^3 \ + \ (\sqrt5 \ + \ 1 )^3 \ - \ 4·(\sqrt5 \ - \ 1)  \ - \ 4·(\sqrt5 \ + \ 1)   \ ] \ \ $$
$$ = \ \ \frac12 · ( \  5\sqrt5 \ + \ 3\sqrt5 \ + \ 5\sqrt5 \ + \ 3\sqrt5 \ - \ 4\sqrt5   \ - \ 4\sqrt5    \ ) \ \ = \ \ 4·\sqrt5 \ \ .  $$

We also note that the slopes of the sides of the square are therefore $ \ m \ = \ -a^2 \ = \ -\frac{1}{\phi} \ $ and $ \ m' \ = \ \frac{1}{a^2} \ = \ \phi \ \  $ (another of many problems on this site in which the Golden Ratio makes a surprise appearance).  A graph to scale of the geometrical situation is shown below.

[image]

Comment: Very nice solution +1. Thank you very much for the citation of my name.